# How to add backlog items in Team Foundation Service

Tags: azure-devops, backlog

The documentation for Team Foundation Service says I should be able to add Backlog items using the menu option on the left as below:

[image: TFS Backlog Items options]

However in my account I don't get this option:

[image: TFS No backlog items option]

How do I enable the ability to add backlog items in TFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is that the items (artifacts) you see or are otherwise able to create depends on the type of process template you create when you create the team project.

In order to get BackLog items with sprint as per the documentation I needed to choose Visual Studio Scrum 3.0 whereas what i had actually done is choose MSF for Agile Software Development.

[image: Create New Project Team]